# No ... when text is too long in UIButton (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

When the text is too long, uibutton will show ..., is it possible to delete ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your button's label's `lineBreakMode`, like so:

**Swift 2.2**

```
var button: UIButton!
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByClipping
```

The possible values for `lineBreakMode` are explained [in Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSLineBreakMode).

`NSLineBreakMode.ByClipping` sounds like the one you want.